# Combining DateSerial with >= & <

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have an Access query to run each month. The dates used in the query refer to an end date of a previous agreement. The below is an extract from the SQL for the data run on March 1st, it returns all information for agreements which ended in February:

```sql
AND ((dbo_agreements_1.end_date)>=#2/1/2016#) AND ((dbo_agreements_1.end_date)<#3/1/2016#));
```

So for the data which will be ran on April 1st (showing agreements ending in March), I would have to change the dates to say:

```sql
 AND ((dbo_agreements_1.end_date)>=#3/1/2016#) AND ((dbo_agreements_1.end_date)<#4/1/2016#));
```

Is there a way of using `DateSerial` here so that it makes the query dynamic (in the sense that I won't have to manually change the dates each month)? I  thought something along the lines of the below might work, but it's returning a mismatch in data type:

```sql
) AND ((dbo_agreements_1.end_date)>=DateSerial(Year([dbo_agreements_1]![end_date]),Month([dbo_agreements_1]![end_date])-1,1)) AND ((dbo_agreements_1.end_date)<DateSerial(Year([dbo_agreements_1]![end_date]),Month([dbo_agreements_1]![end_date]),1)));
```

Comment: Is this what you're after? `dbo_agreements_1.end_date >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) -1, 1) AND dbo_agreements_1.end_date < DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1)`

Comment: @HansUp - will that work in January?

Comment: Sure, `DateSerial()` is smart about that.  When month piece = 1, subtracting 1, gives you last month of the previous year ... December.  Check it out with this simple example: `DateSerial(Year(#2016-1-1#), Month(#2016-1-1#) - 1, 1)` returns 12/1/2015 (that is in m/d/yyyy format).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1)` will give you the first day of the current month.

`DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) - 1, 1)` will give you the first day of the previous month.

So include a combined condition like this in your query's `WHERE` clause:

```sql
    dbo_agreements_1.end_date >= DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()) -1, 1)
AND dbo_agreements_1.end_date < DateSerial(Year(Date()), Month(Date()), 1)
```